# Python click bot TypeError: an integer is required #CookieClickerV2

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies

Help I got stuck. I want to make a auto clicker for "cookie clicker 2". You know. I love cookies and I want them fast :P..... soooo I wrote this script:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui
import random
import time
import os

menu = []
mouseClick = []
stop = []
x = []
y = []

def menu():
    x = input("Geef de X as op >> ")
    y = input("Geef de Y as op >> ")
    mouseClick()

def mouseClick():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y,))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    stop()
    mouseClick()

def stop():
    exit = win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,1,1)
    if exit:
        menu()

menu()
```

I got the following Debug Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "" """File Location """ \Click Module.py", line 31, in <module>
    menu()
  File "" """File Location """ \Click Module.py", line 14, in menu
    mouseClick()
  File " """File Location """ \Click Module.py", line 17, in mouseClick
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y,))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Please save my day and give me cookies <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` are initialized as lists and aren't modified within the functions(You need to make them [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)). Even if they were they would be `str`, so you will need to do something like:

```
x = int(input("Geef de X as op >> ")) 
y = int(input("Geef de Y as op >> "))
```

And the entire code would look something like:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui
import random
import time
import os

menu = []
mouseClick = []
stop = []
x = None
y = None

def menu():
    global x
    global y
    x = int(input("Geef de X as op >> ")) 
    y = int(input("Geef de Y as op >> ")) 
    mouseClick()

def mouseClick():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y,))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    stop()
    mouseClick()

def stop():
    exit = win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,1,1)
    if exit:
        menu()

menu()
```

Comment: Corrected the code bug. The `globals` should work now

Comment: Glad it worked. Hopefully these aren't the ever persistent web cookies. They give me indigestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the fast responds!

My code is as followed:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui
import random
import time
import os

menu = []
mouseClick = []
stop = []


def menu():
    globals x,y
    x = int(input("Geef de X as op >> ")) 
    y = int(input("Geef de Y as op >> ")) 
    mouseClick()

def mouseClick():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y,))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    time.sleep(5)
    stop()
    mouseClick()

def stop():
    exit = win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,1,1)
    if exit:
        menu()

menu()
```

My debug code said:

```
  File "D:\Projecten\Runescape\RS_Bot_RuneMouse\Click Module.py", line 12
    globals x,y
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the observation of global?